# cable with two pins and metal shield

Tags: cable

What type of cable is this? I can't find the device it originally belonged to. The other end is USB.

[image]

Comment: If the other end is a USB 2.0 connector and there are only two pins on the end showing, it's a good bet that it's a power (or power supplement) cable.

Comment: "Guessing games" aren't a good fit for Super User because they generally aren't useful to others. You need the picture to know what the question relates to. So even if someone else had the same question, they would have no way to find your question or any answers.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! This is my first time using stack exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logo on the adapter looks to me to be a [FitBit](https://www.google.com/search?q=fitbit) logo.

[image]

As to which device in-particular, I am not sure.